# Meaning of underscore in case ()

Tags: haskell, switch-statement

So I've seen the syntax around for

```
case () of _
   | someBool ->
   | someOtherBool ->
```

I understand what it does, e.g. toggle a case completely independently of the thing being evaluated by case (which makes sense, as in this case that would be unit, and it will always be unit).

I also understand that this can and (should) work independently of the thing being checked with case (eg (1 == 1) (someComplexFunction)), but that obviously unit is the fastest.

What I don't quite understand, is how the underscore works. It clearly informs the case to completely ignore the contents of the operand and just check for booleans. But where does this operator come from? And in what other contexts can I use it?

Comment: It's the pattern of the alternative. You could also have written `a` instead in this particular example, except that `_` does not bind the matched value to any variable.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As @Rhymoid said in the comment, it is just a pattern match with nothing being bound and it could be replaced by a name (which would be bound). It might be more clear to write it like this:

```
case () of
  _ | someBool -> ...
    | somOtherBool -> ...
```

This could also be written (more or less equivalently) as

```
case () of
  () | someBool -> ...
     | someOtherBool -> ...
```

These are guards. You can also have guards in a more complex `case` match:

```
case m of
  Just x
    | someBool -> ...
    | someOtherBool -> ...
  Nothing
    | someThirdBool -> ...
    | someFourthBool -> ...
```

with as many guards as you want in each match.

The reason to write the code you have given is a trick to get a succinct if-then-else style thing with several possibilities. The original code can be better written with the `MultiWayIf` extension enabled:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiWayIf #-}
...
  if | someBool -> ...
     | someOtherBool -> ...
```

`MultiWayIf` can also be used with any number of Boolean "cases," like the original code.

An underscore can be used in any pattern match for any pattern where you don't need the value later. For example:

```
andBool True True = True
andBool _    _    = False
```

or

```
f (Just _) = 'J'
f _        = 'N'
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer! Everything is very clear now :)